# Webmail clients changing inline CSS

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, inline

I am new to html/css. I am trying to write a somewhat complex html/css formatted email to display in webmail clients like yahoo, gmail, outlook, etc.

In Gmail everything works ok.

However, in yahoo, my formatted html/inline css inside ,

```
<li style="..."> text </li>
```

brackets is displayed as plain text.

In outlook, I get a

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

added to the beginning of the message in the html mime part. When I forward the message as a rfc822 message, this tag is not added and it displays ok.

So I think these webmail clients have their own rules that they display inline CSS by.

Could someone please explain to me the rules to format inline css in email?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that because gmail is fixing your broken HTML? Or is that typo in the question only?

Comment: No I don't think there's any broken html, everything displays perfectly fine inside a broswer

Comment: You probably want to proof-read your question...

Comment: Sure, where is the problem? You mean <li style> instead of <li-style>? I fixed that..

Comment: You have two HTML snippets in your question, one of them is invalid. The first one, in case that doesn't help narrow it down ;)